# How do I evenly distribute topology?

Tags: modeling, mesh

How the do I create a model with EVENLY
spread topology?!

￼That this is one of the most basic stuff on topology, especially if you intent to sculpt on your model.

I couldn't find any answer to that question.

Comment: try yo use a smooth modifier, if it is for an organic model...

Comment: You can select all the vertices in an area where you want to even out the spacing and press Smooth Vertex several times.  (Smooth Vertex is in the Mesh tools area of the Tool Tab in the Tool editor.)

Answer (score 2):

If you mean maintain a more-or-less **even mesh density** (and *appropriate* mesh density), this is something you need to pay attention to throughout the modeling process and adjust for as you go. It's not like you just push a button and make it even.

If you notice at some point that an area is too dense, [dissolving](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/basics/deleting.html) edge loops, [sliding edges](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/edges.html#edge-slide), and [smoothing geometry](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/transform/smooth.html) are some common operations that can help you maintain consistency.